# How to access a single core data object

Tags: core-data, swiftui

In a core data entity containing multiple objects, how to access a specific object outside of using `ForEach`

I have tried using filtering the results with `NSPredicate` but that does not work even when only one object fits the description

For example, I want to be able to edit something outside the `ForEach`
loop, and update it into the latest core data entry

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @FetchRequest(entity: NameData.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var names : FetchedResults<NameData>
    
    var body: some View{
        
        VStack{
            Text("Edit Latest Entry")
            // Textfields for editing first and last names
            ForEach(self.names){ name in
                Text(name.firstName)
                Text(name.lastName)
            }
        }
    }
}
```